# Umbraco 7.2 Forms (not Contour) - Customize the Email work flow

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I'm using the new form feature in umbraco 7.2 and have a few forms set up, all working. I can see the enteries in the back office.

What I now want to do is set up a work flow that sends an email when the form is submitted, but I want to send the content of the form in the email, but I don't want to send everything thats is in the email only some of the fields.

Any ideas of how to do this?

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this? I'm interested in this as well.

Comment: @howlee yes I did, you have to select the send email using XSLT transformation, then select a XSLT file that will create the HTML email

Answer (score 1):

The workflows in the new forms work exactly the same as the ones in the older version apparently. You can create your own custom workflow using something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web;
using System.Xml;
using Umbraco.Forms.Core;
using Umbraco.Forms.Core.Attributes;
using Umbraco.Forms.Core.Enums;
using Umbraco.Forms.Data.Storage;

namespace WebApp.Contour
{
    public class SendEmailToUser : WorkflowType
    {
        // Generates the new workflow details for Contour in the workflow dropdown in Contour
        public SendEmailToUser()
        {
            // Need to generate a new guid for the new custom workflow - add your own GUID
            this.Id = new Guid("PLACE GUID HERE");
            this.Name = "PUT WORKFLOW NAME HERE";
            this.Description = "PUT WORKFLOW DESCRIPTION HERE";
    }

    public override List<Exception> ValidateSettings()
    {
        List<Exception> exceptions = new List<Exception>();

        //if you have any settings, validate them here

        return exceptions;
    }

    public override Umbraco.Forms.Core.Enums.WorkflowExecutionStatus Execute(Record record, RecordEventArgs e)
    {
        //place your workflow execution logic here, "record" gives you access to the fields on the submitted record            

        return WorkflowExecutionStatus.Completed;
    }
}
```

For more details on how to code workflows, have a look at the examples in this tutorial: [creating a quiz in Contour](http://www.nibble.be/?p=83)

Comment: I think the OP is referring to the new umbraco forms engine part of 7.2 (ie - he is not using contour). I would be interested in the answer to this as well.

Comment: They use the same engine for Workflows, so this code should work for both, according to Tim Geysens, the guy who maintains Contour/Umbraco Forms.